# Convert String input to working VB code

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to convert, say, a textbox input to working code?

For example, user types 'if x<10 then y=2 else y=5' into textbox1, it gets used directly as code something like ...

```
dim x as integer = 5
dim y as integer = 0
include processed textbox1.text
resultbox.text = (y*20).tostring
```

It's not important why this would be needed - just whether there is any straight-forward method that parses a string to code.

Many thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325180/vb-net-run-script-inside-textbox/23340162#23340162

Comment: Does it have to run as code as it is, or can you parse the input text to get the required parts and act on them as appropriate?

Comment: yes the code has to run as if it were written as code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12852/Compile-and-Run-VB-NET-Code-using-the-CodeDom

Comment: Thanks Alu. As with Matt's suggestion below I'll have to work through the demo for this to see exactly what it does. I was keeping fingers crossed for a simple 'compileThis' kinda class but looks like will be a significant amount of investigating :)

Comment: I'm currently working through this and looking at implementing it within my form. Hopefully all goes smoothly. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this using the [VBCodeProvider class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.vbcodeprovider(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2). Although the amount of code required is quite significant:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5472/Compiling-NET-code-on-the-fly

Comment: Thanks Matt - this looks a bit over my head at the moment but could well be what I need. I'll try to run through the demo tomorrow to see if it becomes clearer when running an actual test.

Comment: I've had a look at this and the VBCodeProvider does indeed seem to be what I need. This link will help others with similar issues though I think Alu's link is more suitable for my personal abilities and needs. Many thanks again for confirming the feasibility of this.